Get categories of arrow chunkedarray
If I have a PyArrow chunkedarray and want to know all its categories, I can go through each individual array, get the categories from there, and find the union:
import pyarrow as pa
import functools

# setup
one = pa.array(["a", "b", None, "d"], pa.dictionary(pa.int64(), pa.utf8()))
two = pa.array(["a", "b", None, "d", 'e'], pa.dictionary(pa.int64(), pa.utf8()))
ca = pa.chunked_array([one, two])

# operation:
cats = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, (set(x.dictionary) for x in ca.chunks))
out = pa.chunked_array([list(cats)])

This works, but feels quite convoluted - is there a better way?

Not really. Depending on how the chunked array was constructed, the chunks may share the same dictionary, but not in this case.
A code simplification and optimization (but the same technique):
pa.chunked_array(x.dictionary for x in ca.chunks).unique()

